# Windows make application to run at system startup (user login)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to make my application launch at user login (system startup). 
I found such solution:

**app.manifest**

```
<requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

**PreferencesWindows.xaml.cs**

```
 if (ServerSettings.ShouldApplicationAutostart)
  {
      SystemStartupService.AddThisAppToCurrentUserStartup(); 
  } else
  {
       SystemStartupService.DeleteThisAppFromCurrentUserStartup(); 
  }
```

**SystemStartupService.cs**

```
 public static void AddThisAppToCurrentUserStartup()
        {
            AddAppToCurrentUserStartup(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name,
                                       Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location, true); 
        }

        public static void AddAppToCurrentUserStartup(string appName, string appPath, bool asBackground) { 
            using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                registryKey.SetValue(appName, "\"" + appPath + "\"" + (asBackground ? " /background" : "") ); 
            }
        }

        public static void DeleteThisAppFromCurrentUserStartup()
        {
            DeleteAppFromCurrentUserStartup(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name);
        }

        public static void DeleteAppFromCurrentUserStartup(string appName)
        {
            using (RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true))
            {
                registryKey.DeleteValue(appName, false);
            }
        }
```

Problem is that this solution doesn't work for my app and I don't know why. The above code successfully adds entries in **registry** and **System Configuration > Startup**

**regedit**
[image]

**TaskManager**[image]

If it matters this is simple wpf application running in notification try.

**Problem: Application do not start at user login!**

Comment: I guess your appPath is wrong.

Comment: No, it is correct when I copy paste it it points to directory with .exe file. I think maybe there is problem with Debug version so I made Release and copy it to Program Files, and it also doesn't work

Comment: This works without any code if you place the right text in the registry key, so the only thing you can be doing wrong is that either path is wrong or the file is not accessible.

Comment: If I have entered path to other application installed on my system it was launched at startup. If I get and copy my app path and paste to cmd tool it also starts but not starts at system startup. Maybe there are some requirements for application to start at startup? Otherwise it is blocked?

Comment: Maybe the app should be signed with some certificate, as I have publisher field empty in Task Manager?

Comment: Possibly you have some anti virus software that disables this. Try to turn it off.

Comment: I only have Windows Defender default antivirus in Windows 10

Comment: I have made new simple project with one window and one button for setting registry entry. With this simple app solution seems to work it starts at runtime. Maybe there is something preventing it from autorun in my code. I must investigate it.

Comment: I still think that your appPath is wrong, that can be the only explanation. Can you debug copy appPath to cmd and see if the app runs at all?

Answer (score 0):

The above solution works correctly. I have some error in code in MainWindow.cs which cause that app couldn't start correctly. Moreover it was in OnInitialized() method which prevents Debugger from showing this error while autorun of app failed. This error was related to bad icon path (I have been using loading Icon resource from Assembly directory which work perfectly while running app directly from Visual Studio but files with odd path (not found image file) when auto launching app at startup).